# bash shell: variable output issue for string compare

Tags: bash

I wrote a shell program that reads a string comparison of two files.

String comparison succeeds, but has failed to output a comparison string .

`echo $ line, ${array [a]}` was not even entered in the $ line output.

To verify that the problem is variable, it changed the order behind the front this time `${array [a]}` has not been output.

How do the two have to print at the same time.

Advice please.

Code :

```
a=0    
count=0
while read line    
do    
    count=`expr $count + 1`           
    if [ $count -gt 6 ]         
    then                       
         array[count]=$line
    fi
done < $FILE2

while read line
do
        a=`expr $a + 1`

                if [ $a -gt 6 ] && [ $a -le 10 ]
                then
                        if [ "$line" != "${array[a]}" ]
                                then
                                        echo $line, ${array[a]}
                        fi
done < $FILE1
```

Comment: there is a missing `fi` before last line of code... it was probably missed out.. either way, http://www.shellcheck.net/ will catch such syntax errors and then suggest improvements in given script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed a couple of syntax errors. Following works for me:

```
a=0
count=0
while read line    
do
    count=`expr $count + 1`
    if [ $count -gt 6 ]
    then
         array[$count]=$line
    fi
done < $FILE2

while read line
do
        a=`expr $a + 1`

                if [ $a -gt 6 ] && [ $a -le 10 ]
                then
                        if [ "$line" != "${array[a]}" ]
                                then
                                        echo $line, ${array[a]}
                        fi
                fi
done < $FILE1
```

Fixed a missing `fi` a missing `$` on `array[count]` and ...

Comment: It is missing the "fi" is my mistake. The code is written.